# get function in perl w/ website does not produce a value inside the perl script

Tags: perl, web, null, get

I'm trying to get index.pl?home=home to produce the value 'home' within my perl script, or home=anything to produce 'anything'.

For some reason I'm not using the GET method correctly.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);
$cgi = new CGI;
$home = $cgi->param('home');
```

---

What am I doing wrong?  I've searched and searched for this SPECIFIC answer...

Comment: OK now it's working just fine, I took out an extra value = value2 link in-between that was causing the error!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.  My full script looks like this:

```
#!C:/perl/bin/perl.exe

use CGI qw(:standard);
$cgi = new CGI;
$home = $cgi->param('home');

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n";
print "\n";
print "Hello world\n";
print "Hello $home world\n";
```

(I'm on Windows, but that shouldn't matter.)

When I visit `http://localhost/stack.pl?home=xx` I see:

```
Hello world
Hello xx world
```

Comment: That's exactly what I thought and nearly identical to what I'm trying to do... but it shows up as a blank value for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `$cgi->header();` to your script. You're most probably running into a "`Premature end of script headers`" error:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);
$cgi = new CGI;
$home = $cgi->param('home');

print $cgi->header();
print $home
```

Check your error_log for details.